# What is use of custom option SKU in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Will the order display the SKU Number you input for the Custom Options? What if there is 4 different Custom Options to choose from, and each Custom Option has a individual SKU, how will that work?

Answer (score 1):

The option SKU is a suffix to the product SKU. Check this link for better understanding.
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html

Answer (score 1):

SKU is just an identifier of product out of the system you can say in physical store godown, So If you have same product in different variant and with different SKU then you can add custom option with that sku. In storefront while reviewing product it will not affect anywhere it will just show the main product sku but once you have placed the order with selecting custom option then custom option SKU will be shown in order detail page with MAINPRODUCT_SKU-CUSTOM_OPTION_SKU.

Answer (score 0):

1. SKU is only for products.
2. It should be unique.
3. But products are not identified by SKU, they have unique ID. You can see it by $_product->getId();
4. However you can filter product or fetch any particular product by its SKU by,

   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('SKU','Your Value');

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean with order display. But the SKU for the custom option will be shown when selected and will then be appended to the product it's "default" sku.
Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the SKU in there, magento will adjust the stock levels of the corresponding product SKU if that option is selected by the user.